# Designing ICSP pin header while SPI slave present?

Tags: spi, atmega328p, isp

Is this portion of my schematic accurate for designing an ICSP header while there is an SPI slave? The four SPI net labels also go to the respective hardware on my 328P. I have CS (where I believe NSS is active low as per the datasheet) on a pullup resistor because I read that it was necessary to keep the slave off the SPI bus while it was being programmed. Can anyone confirm that this is right?

[image]

[image]